# "no matching function call" with templated functions project

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a program to generate and sort an array of random numbers.
The compiler gives me the following error:

> select.cxx: In function ‘void selectionsort(Item*, SizeType)
>   [withItem = int, SizeType = long unsigned int]’:
>           select.cxx:95:   instantiated from here
>           select.cxx:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘swap(int*&, long unsigned int&, long unsigned int&)’

Here is my code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

template <class Item, class SizeType>
void selectionsort(Item data[], SizeType n)
{
    for (SizeType i = 0; i = n - 2; i++)
    {
        SizeType j = index_of_minimal(data, i, n);
        swap(data, i, j); //data[i] swapped with data[j](minimum)
    }
}

template <class Item, class SizeType>
std::size_t index_of_minimal(const Item data[], SizeType i, SizeType n)
{
    size_t min = i; //holds index of minimum (initialized to i)
    Item t1 = data[i];  //temporary holder for comparing values, initialized as i (starting value)
    Item t2;        //second holder

    for (SizeType j = i++; j = n - 1; j++)
    {
        t2 = data[j];

        if (t2 < t1)
        {
            t1 = data[j];
            min = j;
        }
    }

    return min;
}

template <class Item, class SizeType>
void swap(Item data[], SizeType i, SizeType j) //data[i] swapped with data[j](minimum)
{
    Item temp; //holds value to be swapped
    temp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[j];
    data[j] = temp;
}

template <class Item, class SizeType>
void listPrint(Item data[ ], SizeType n)
{
    cout << "array:";

    for (SizeType i = 0; i = n - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << data[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int myrand(int lower, int upper)
{
    return (lower + rand() % ( upper - lower + 1 )  );
}

int main()
{
    size_t n; //user input

//For random number generator//
    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "Please enter a number:" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    while (n < 1)
    {
        cout << "Error: please enter a number 1 or larger" << endl;
        cin >> n;
    }

    int rNumbers[n]; //declares int array of size n
    int randomN;    //to hold randomly generated number

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        randomN = myrand(1, 1000); //generates a random number as randomN
        rNumbers[i] = randomN;
    }

    cout << "Unsorted ";
    listPrint(rNumbers, n);
    selectionsort(rNumbers, n);
    cout << "Sorted ";
    listPrint(rNumbers, n);

}
```

I have a feeling that the problem has to do with the data types passed to the swap function. I am also confused as to why the first line of the error states that `SizeType = long unsigned int`, when the data type of `n` as declared in `main()` is `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the other functions you call inside your template function are visible. So, define `selection_sort()` **after** `swap()` and `index_of_minimal()`.

Side remark:

```
int rNumbers[n]; //declares int array of size n
```

declares a variable sized array, which is not standard C++ (some compilers support it though, but you shouldn't rely on this). If you want a run-time sized array, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Regarding your confusion at the end, `size_t` is a type alias, which in your implementation it happens to be for `unsigned long int`, so that's why the error mentions it.

Comment: This fixed the error, thank you very much! and thanks for the side remark.